# Angular 2 Dynamically generated form with multiple checkbox not working

Tags: json, angular, forms, templates, dynamic

I am dynamically generating HTML Form based on a JSON. I am using the official example provided here: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

I am trying to extend this example to have other controls in my dynamic form (textarea, radio button, checkbox, etc.). I have been able to achieve all controls, except for checkbox. Though the checkbox is visible on the screen, the value is not captured in its enclosing form.

My Checkbox definition goes like this:

```
import { QuestionBase } from './question-base-model';

export interface Values{
  label: string;
  value: string;
  isChecked: boolean;
}
export class CheckBoxQuestion extends QuestionBase<boolean> {
  controlType = 'checkbox';
  options: Values[] = [];

  constructor(options: {} = {}) {
    super(options);
    this.options = options['options'] || [];
  }
}
```

My JSON for checkbox is like this:

```
{
    key: 'sideDish',
    label: 'Side dish',
    type: 'checkbox',
    order: 10,
    name: 'sides',
    options: [
      {value: 'fries', isChecked: true, label: 'French Fries'},
      {value: 'cheese', isChecked: false, label: 'Cheese'},
      {value: 'sauce', isChecked: true, label: 'Tomato Sauce'}
    ]
  }
```

And my Dynamic HTML template is as below:

```
<div [formGroup]="form" >
  <label [attr.for]="question.key">{{question.label}}</label>

  <div [ngSwitch]="question.controlType">
  <!-- Checkbox -->
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'">
      <span *ngFor="let opt of question.options; let i = index">
          <input type="checkbox" 
            [formControlName]="question.key"
            [id]="i+'_'+question.key" 
            [value]="opt.value">
          <label [attr.for]="i+'_'+question.key">{{opt.label}}</label>
      </span>      
    </div>
 </div>
```

The FormControl code goes like this (no edits made here from the original example):

```
toFormGroup(questions: QuestionBase<any>[] ) {
    let group: any = {};

    questions.forEach(question => {
      let validatorsArray = [];

      if(question.required) validatorsArray.push(Validators.required);

      group[question.key] = validatorsArray.length > 0 ? new FormControl(question.value || '', Validators.compose(validatorsArray)) : new FormControl(question.value || '');

    });

    return new FormGroup(group);
```

This method is consumed in the init function:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions);
  }
```

When I hit on Submit button, I am printing the "form.value". Rest all the controls prints with the value I have set in the form. But, an empty string as value for this checkbox.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you create FormGroup in your typescript code? If yes, please share code for this.

Comment: Have updated the code.

Comment: Try to remove ``[value]="opt.value"`` from input tag, because you set the value by generating the FormControls.

Comment: I would need that because, the JSON might optionally contain values already set. Anyways, removal did not help solving the issue.

Comment: Can you maybe create simple demo application with your data on https://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: Thanks for your interest! I will create the app and let you know.

Comment: Could not create the demo app, but I found adding a custom library for multi-select checkbox was more easier than the native. I guess to go with native approach for dynamic form generation, we should rather stick on to single value checkbox.